Use and manage mail addresses in cPanel (Namecheap) when domain is registered on Hostinger
I registered a domain at Hostinger. Currently the corresponding website is hosted at Hostinger like multiple e-mail accounts as well.
Since Hostinger is quite expansive providing more than 1 GB webspace per e-mail account, I want to transfer the e-mail accounts to Namecheap and keep the hosting of the website at Hostinger.
Is this possible? I guess I have to edit the DNS MX records, isn`t it?
Thanks in advance.
